# How to load multiple language files in i18next

Tags: react-native, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I want to add translations for my React Native application and I want to make sure that I do it in a maintainable manner. So I decided that every of my feature will have a locale folder with all the translations as json files.

```
|-feature1
|---locale
|-----de.json
|-----en.json
|-feature2
|---locale
|-----de.json
|-----en.json
```

Now how can I make sure that i18next only loads the required files? The documentation always either use a ressource object with all translations in it (I want to avoid to load all json files for all name spaces and languages into memory) or a http backend plugin.

Is there no way to dynamically load bundled translations?